# Android Studio Starter Guide

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am following Google's starter guide for android studio and I am having trouble at [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) step. Specifically the Note below

> Note: The XML layout generated by previous versions of Android Studio might not include the android:id attribute. The call findViewById() will fail if the layout does not have the android:id attribute. If this is the case, open activity_display_message.xml and add the attribute android:id="@+id/activity_display_message" to the layout element.

I am not sure where to add `android:id="@+id/activity_display_message"` to my activity_display_message.xml file?

DisplayMessageActivity.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);

        ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.activity_display_message);
        layout.addView(textView);
    }
}
```

activity_display_message.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.nathan.googledemo.DisplayMessageActivity">


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's only one View in the Layout, so it should be the one with that id:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_display_message"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.nathan.googledemo.DisplayMessageActivity">


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

As it is written in note add this attribute to layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_display_message"//Here is it
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.nathan.googledemo.DisplayMessageActivity">


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add it anywhere within a layout, the order of specific attributes doesn't matter.

So this:

```
<RelativeLayout     
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_display_message"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.nathan.googledemo.DisplayMessageActivity">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Is functionally identical to this:

```
<RelativeLayout     
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.nathan.googledemo.DisplayMessageActivity"
    android:id="@+id/activity_display_message">
</RelativeLayout>
```